Join expression not supported in join query Access
I would like to ask for your assistance why am I getting this error:
"JOIN expression not supported"
Code:
SELECT
    t2.KPICode1 AS OrigCode,
    t0.KPITask AS OrigTask,
    t2.ID AS TimID,
    t2.Score AS OrigScore,
    t3.ID AS AccID,
    t3.Score AS DepScore,
    t1.KPICode AS DepCode,
    t1.KPITask AS DepTask,
    IIF(ISNULL(t4.RevCount), 0, t4.RevCount) AS RevCount
FROM
    (((KPI_qryMain AS t0
    LEFT JOIN KPI_qryMain AS t1 ON t1.KPICode = t0.ChildKPICode)
    LEFT JOIN KPI AS t2 ON t2.KPICode = t0.KPICode)
    LEFT JOIN KPI AS t3 ON t3.KPICode = t0.ChildKPICode AND t3.UserID = t2.UserID)
    LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT COUNT(*) AS RevCount, RefNum
     FROM KPI_tblLogs
     WHERE Title = 'Daily Task'
     AND LogDetails LIKE '%For revision%'
     GROUP BY RefNum) AS t4 ON t4.RefNum = CSTR(t2.ID)
WHERE
    t2.DueDate = #8/12/2024 6:00:00 PM#
    AND t3.DueDate = #8/12/2024 6:00:00 PM#
    AND t0.KPICode = 'SRSMRT03'
    AND t2.UserID = 'XXX000165'


I reckon this code should not be generating that error.  Did you post the correct query?

Hi @TimBiegeleisen thank you for your reply. yes this is the correct query.

What is the SQL of KPI_qryMain? Could it have multiple UserID fields?

Hi @June7 theres not UserID field in KPI_qryMain. only KPICode

t0 is alias for KPI_qryMain and your SQL references t0.UserID so KPI_qryMain must have at least one UserID field.

apologies. i made a wrong query. instead of t0.UserID, already changed to t2.UserID. but the error changed to Join expression not supported.

Maybe because of t0.ChildKPICode in the same JOIN.

You have an 'ambiguous join' among t0, t2, and t3.
You can turn the parts, barring t3, into a subquery and then LEFT JOIN that to T3, like this (not the only way, of course):
SELECT
         T0124.OrigCode
       , T0124.OrigTask
       , T0124.TimID
       , T0124.OrigScore
       , T3.ID as AccID
       , T3.Score as DepScore
       , T0124.DepCode
       , T0124.DepTask
       , T0124.RevCount

FROM
  (
   SELECT
         t2.KPICode AS OrigCode
       , t0.KPITask AS OrigTask
       , t2.ID AS TimID
       , t2.Score AS OrigScore
       , t1.KPICode AS DepCode
       , t1.KPITask AS DepTask
       , IIf(t4.RevCount is null,0,t4.RevCount) AS RevCount
       , t2.UserID as t2_UserID
       , t0.ChildKPICode as t0_ChildKPICode
    FROM 
         (((KPI_qryMain AS t0

         INNER JOIN KPI AS t2
         ON t0.KPICode = t2.KPICode)

         LEFT JOIN KPI_qryMain AS t1
         ON t0.ChildKPICode = t1.KPICode)

         LEFT JOIN (SELECT COUNT(*) AS RevCount, RefNum

                     FROM KPI_tblLogs

                     WHERE Title = 'Daily Task'

                     AND LogDetails LIKE '*For revision*'

                     GROUP BY RefNum)  AS t4

          ON cstr(t2.ID) = t4.RefNum)

    WHERE  t2.DueDate="#12/08/2024 6:00:00 PM#"

       AND t0.KPICode='xxxxx'

       AND t2.UserID='yyyyyyy'

      ) AS T0124

     

      LEFT JOIN KPI AS t3

      ON (t2_UserID = t3.UserID AND T0124.t0_ChildKPICode = t3.KPICode)


I changed your wildcard characters to * because this is for MsAccess and DAO; but if you are going to call this from ADO, you can change them back to %.
I also changed your LEFT JOIN between t0 and t2 to INNER JOIN, because with the criteria on the WHERE clause for t2 LEFT join will not have any difference.
